# shell case pattern [...] disallowed chars

Tags: bash, sh, posix

Bracket expressions within case patterns seem to disallow `[() &;]`. However I can't seem to find any such restrictions (or escaping workarounds) in the [POSIX shell spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), or in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) for that matter.

```
case '&' in
# *[&]*)  echo y ;;  # won't parse
  *[\&]*) echo y ;;  # will parse & work
esac
# similar for ';', ' ', '(', ')'
# not a problem for ${var#[&; ()]}
```

This is in a `sh` shell script function that can't afford to call external utilities (but I'm curious about `bash` too). So... is there any spec that describes backslash-ing these characters within a bracket expression pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think it is explicitly documented anywhere.

But it can be deduced that [Token Recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) Rule 6 is applied while the pattern list is being parsed. That is, unless quoted, [control operators](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_113), [redirection operators](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_318), and end of input are recognized as operators, and delimit a pattern. The shell expects `|` (indicates that another pattern follows) or `)` (marks the end of the pattern list) to do that; and anything else causes a parse error.

As square brackets have no special meaning to the parser during tokenization, whether an operator occurs between them is irrelevant. And `${var#[&; ()]}` is a different case; covered in [Token Recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) Rule 5 and [Parameter Expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).